# A simple probability problem

Tags: probability

There are $n$ applicants for the director of computing. The applicants are interviewed independently by each member of the three-person search committee and ranked from $1$ to $n$. A candidate will be hired if he or she is ranked first by at least two of the three interviewers. Find the probability that a candidate will be accepted if the members of the committee really have no ability at all to judge the candidates and just rank the candidates randomly.

My reasoning:

- There are $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2)$ many ways the interviewers put a different person at the first position.
- So, $n^3 - n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2)$ ways that at least two interviewers will put the same person at the first position
- So, $\frac{n^3 - n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2)}{n^3} = \frac{3n^2-2n}{n^3}$ is the desired probability

But the answer given is $\frac{3n-2}{n^3}$

Where is the problem in my reasoning? thanks.

Comment: The question is ambiguous and the difference in answers seems to hinge on that ambiguity: is it asking the chance that *some* candidate will be accepted or the chance that *a particular candidate* will be accepted?  Because it's impossible for more than one candidate to be accepted, the probability of the former must be $n$ times the probability of the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that the second interviewer puts a different person at the first position is

$$\frac{n-1}{n}\,.$$

The probability that the third interviewer puts a different person at the first position is

$$\frac{n-2}{n}\,.$$

Hence, the probability that there are three different persons at the first position is

$$p(\text{all different})=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n} = \frac{n^2-3n+2}{n^2} \,.$$

The contrary of three different persons at the first position is *not* three different persons at the first position (i.e., at least two times the same person is at position one). Therefore, we calculate

$$p(\text{at least two identical}) = p(\lnot\text{all different}) = 1 - p(\text{all different}) =\\1-\frac{n^2-3n+2}{n^2} = \frac{3n-2}{n^2}\,.$$

Comment: Hi Sven, you have found exactly the same answer with me, but the given answer in the text book is different, note the $n^3$ at the denominator.

Comment: Might still be a typo.

Comment: You can understand the question as relating to a specific candidate being selected and not just any candidate. In this case you have to multiply your result by 1/n.

Answer (score 2):

${3\choose2} \cdot 1/n \cdot 1/n \cdot (1 - 1/n)$ --this represents two out of the three committee members  selecting the same individual times the third committee member selecting a different person.

${3\choose3} \cdot 1/n \cdot  1/n \cdot  1/n$ --this represents all three committee members selecting the same individual.

Add the two up:

$$ \array{
&   & 3 \cdot 1/n^2 \cdot (n-1)/n + 1/n^3 & = \\
& = & 3(n-1)/n^3 + 1/n^3 & = \\
& = & (3n - 3)/n^3 + 1/n^3 & = \\
& = & (3n - 3 + 1)/n^3 & = \\
& = & (3n - 2)/n^3
}$$

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I believe you obtain a different answer than the existing one because you interpret the question differently.